# How does a boolean control's value get handled across system locales?

Tags: vba, checkbox, registry

I have a simple bit of VBA code in a form that saves the current boolean state of a CheckBox control to the VBA area of the Windows registry:

```
SaveSetting sAppName, sSection, sKey, CheckBox1
```

Similarly, the state of the CheckBox is initialised, with a default value of True, as follows:

```
CheckBox1 = GetSetting(sAppName, sSection, sKey, "True")
```

This works as expected until I discovered that the SaveSetting line fails with err 94 "Invalid use of null" on a Dutch user's PC.

After checking the Dutch user's registry, the value was set to "Waar" which is Dutch for True. So, when the CheckBox is initialised, it's value is being set to "Waar" and then saving the setting fails as "Waar" is not recognised as True and the CheckBox value is returned as Null.

I was surprised to see the boolean value being saved locale-aware although I have been unable to replicate the behaviour by setting my system locale to Dutch.

What is going on here and what is the correct way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not come across that but maybe (I don't have a Dutch PC!)

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.CheckBox1 = GetSetting("TEST", "Section", "Key", True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = -1 Then
    SaveSetting "TEST", "Section", "Key", True
    Else
    SaveSetting "TEST", "Section", "Key", False
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I've done something similar e.g. checking the value of the checkbox and then explicitly saving "True" or "False" to the registry. Maybe this is one of those questions that ends up with a workaround rather than understanding what is actually going on ;-)

Comment: I've run into the same thing; best explat I have for it is that you're SaveSetting/GetSetting always work with strings, so your Boolean will be converted to/from a string value, and that will use the local language settings.  Explicitly saving "True"/"False" seems the best way 'round this.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this works as expected here (saving values on a US English system, reading them back on same).  Saving values on a system in English then reading them back in Dutch or vice versa, I would expect to fail.

```
Sub test()
    SaveSetting "TestApp", "TestSection", "TestTrueKey", True
    SaveSetting "TestApp", "TestSection", "TestFalseKey", False
End Sub

Sub getback()
    Dim bTest As Boolean
    bTest = GetSetting("TestApp", "TestSection", "TestTrueKey")
    If bTest Then
        MsgBox "True"
    Else
        MsgBox "False"
    End If

    bTest = GetSetting("TestApp", "TestSection", "TestFalseKey")
    If bTest Then
        MsgBox "True"
    Else
        MsgBox "False"
    End If
End Sub
```

When you assign the return value of GetSetting, a string, to a bool, VBA's doing an implicit conversion; I expect it'd use the locale-specific version of strings for that.

You might want to write a couple wrapper functions of your own:  GetBoolSetting, SaveBoolSetting.